# sqrt function on stm32 arm doesn't work

Tags: math, arm, sqrt, fpu, cortex-m

I'm using an stm32f4 chip (cortex-m4) with an FPU and

sqrt( 9.7 * 9.7 ) returns 94.17..

i am using the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler and don't get any errors on compile.

my makefile is really long because the same file is used for stm32f4 and sam4 chips.  I don't even know the relevant parts to post.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : some flag config from makefile

```
C_FLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb
C_FLAGS += -std=gnu89 -g -ggdb3 -fverbose-asm
C_FLAGS += --param max-inline-insns-single=500
C_FLAGS += -fsingle-precision-constant
C_FLAGS += -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
C_FLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard
C_WARNINGS = -Wall
C_WARNINGS += -Wdouble-promotion
```

This is my exact code:

```
float x, y, z, mag;
x = ((float) (((int32_t) x_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
y = ((float) (((int32_t) y_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
z = ((float) (((int32_t) z_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
DEBUG("XYZ = %.2f, %.2f, %.2f = %.2f\n", x, y, z, mag );
```

The DEBUG macro prints to a debug log on the usb_cdc interface and LCD screen.  Also, i had been overwriting Wdouble-promotion and am now getting a double promotion warning on the DEBUG line (which calls snprintf with `__VA_ARGS__`).  I assume this is not relevant.

I changed the optimization level to 0 (still getting same result with sqrt), this is the .lss:

```
 mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
8019a36:    ed97 7a05   vldr    s14, [r7, #20]
8019a3a:    edd7 7a05   vldr    s15, [r7, #20]
8019a3e:    ee27 7a27   vmul.f32    s14, s14, s15
8019a42:    edd7 6a04   vldr    s13, [r7, #16]
8019a46:    edd7 7a04   vldr    s15, [r7, #16]
8019a4a:    ee66 7aa7   vmul.f32    s15, s13, s15
8019a4e:    ee37 7a27   vadd.f32    s14, s14, s15
8019a52:    edd7 6a03   vldr    s13, [r7, #12]
8019a56:    edd7 7a03   vldr    s15, [r7, #12]
8019a5a:    ee66 7aa7   vmul.f32    s15, s13, s15
8019a5e:    ee77 7a27   vadd.f32    s15, s14, s15
8019a62:    ee17 0a90   vmov    r0, s15
8019a66:    f7e6 fcf3   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8019a6a:    4602        mov r2, r0
8019a6c:    460b        mov r3, r1
8019a6e:    ec43 2b10   vmov    d0, r2, r3
8019a72:    f007 fe9f   bl  80217b4 <sqrt>
8019a76:    ec53 2b10   vmov    r2, r3, d0
8019a7a:    4610        mov r0, r2
8019a7c:    4619        mov r1, r3
8019a7e:    f7e6 fffd   bl  8000a7c <__aeabi_d2f>
8019a82:    4603        mov r3, r0
8019a84:    60bb        str r3, [r7, #8]

 if( 1 ) {
   DEBUG("XYZ = %.2f, %.2f, %.2f = %.2f\n", x, y, z, mag );
8019a86:    6978        ldr r0, [r7, #20]
8019a88:    f7e6 fce2   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8019a8c:    4682        mov sl, r0
8019a8e:    468b        mov fp, r1
8019a90:    6938        ldr r0, [r7, #16]
8019a92:    f7e6 fcdd   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8019a96:    4680        mov r8, r0
8019a98:    4689        mov r9, r1
8019a9a:    68f8        ldr r0, [r7, #12]
8019a9c:    f7e6 fcd8   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8019aa0:    4604        mov r4, r0
8019aa2:    460d        mov r5, r1
8019aa4:    68b8        ldr r0, [r7, #8]
8019aa6:    f7e6 fcd3   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8019aaa:    4602        mov r2, r0
8019aac:    460b        mov r3, r1
8019aae:    e9cd ab00   strd    sl, fp, [sp]
8019ab2:    e9cd 8902   strd    r8, r9, [sp, #8]
8019ab6:    e9cd 4504   strd    r4, r5, [sp, #16]
8019aba:    e9cd 2306   strd    r2, r3, [sp, #24]
8019abe:    f243 707c   movw    r0, #14204  ; 0x377c
8019ac2:    f6c0 0002   movt    r0, #2050   ; 0x802
8019ac6:    f240 4176   movw    r1, #1142   ; 0x476
8019aca:    f643 0218   movw    r2, #14360  ; 0x3818
8019ace:    f6c0 0202   movt    r2, #2050   ; 0x802
8019ad2:    f643 430c   movw    r3, #15372  ; 0x3c0c
8019ad6:    f6c0 0302   movt    r3, #2050   ; 0x802
8019ada:    f7ed fee9   bl  80078b0 <debug_log>
```

This is with -O2

```
 x = ((float) (((int32_t) x_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
8010c3e:    eeb0 9a48   vmov.f32    s18, s16
8010c42:    ee10 9aa9   vnmls.f32   s18, s1, s19
 y = ((float) (((int32_t) y_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 z = ((float) (((int32_t) z_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
8010c46:    eef8 1ac1   vcvt.f32.s32    s3, s2
 mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
8010c4a:    ee28 2aa8   vmul.f32    s4, s17, s17
 y_adc = ((int16_t) (buffer[2] & 0xff)) + (((int16_t) (buffer[3] & 0xff))<<8);
 z_adc = ((int16_t) (buffer[4] & 0xff)) + (((int16_t) (buffer[5] & 0xff))<<8);

 x = ((float) (((int32_t) x_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 y = ((float) (((int32_t) y_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 z = ((float) (((int32_t) z_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
8010c4e:    ee11 8aa9   vnmls.f32   s16, s3, s19
 mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
8010c52:    ee09 2a09   vmla.f32    s4, s18, s18
8010c56:    ee08 2a08   vmla.f32    s4, s16, s16
8010c5a:    ee12 0a10   vmov    r0, s4
8010c5e:    f7ef fbf7   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8010c62:    ec41 0b10   vmov    d0, r0, r1
8010c66:    f007 f8f9   bl  8017e5c <sqrt>

 if( 1 ) {
   DEBUG("XYZ = %.2f, %.2f, %.2f = %.2f\n", x, y, z, mag );
8010c6a:    ee19 0a10   vmov    r0, s18
 z_adc = ((int16_t) (buffer[4] & 0xff)) + (((int16_t) (buffer[5] & 0xff))<<8);

 x = ((float) (((int32_t) x_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 y = ((float) (((int32_t) y_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 z = ((float) (((int32_t) z_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
8010c6e:    ec55 4b10   vmov    r4, r5, d0

 if( 1 ) {
   DEBUG("XYZ = %.2f, %.2f, %.2f = %.2f\n", x, y, z, mag );
8010c72:    f7ef fbed   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8010c76:    e9cd 0100   strd    r0, r1, [sp]
8010c7a:    ee18 0a90   vmov    r0, s17
8010c7e:    f7ef fbe7   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8010c82:    e9cd 0102   strd    r0, r1, [sp, #8]
8010c86:    ee18 0a10   vmov    r0, s16
8010c8a:    f7ef fbe1   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8010c8e:    e9cd 0104   strd    r0, r1, [sp, #16]
 z_adc = ((int16_t) (buffer[4] & 0xff)) + (((int16_t) (buffer[5] & 0xff))<<8);

 x = ((float) (((int32_t) x_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 y = ((float) (((int32_t) y_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 z = ((float) (((int32_t) z_adc) + 0x8000)) * scale - offset;
 mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
8010c92:    4629        mov r1, r5
8010c94:    4620        mov r0, r4
8010c96:    f7ef fef1   bl  8000a7c <__aeabi_d2f>

 if( 1 ) {
   DEBUG("XYZ = %.2f, %.2f, %.2f = %.2f\n", x, y, z, mag );
8010c9a:    f7ef fbd9   bl  8000450 <__aeabi_f2d>
8010c9e:    4a0e        ldr r2, [pc, #56]   ; (8010cd8 <LIS331DLH_ReadAc+0x134>)
8010ca0:    4b0e        ldr r3, [pc, #56]   ; (8010cdc <LIS331DLH_ReadAc+0x138>)
8010ca2:    e9cd 0106   strd    r0, r1, [sp, #24]
8010ca6:    4808        ldr r0, [pc, #32]   ; (8010cc8 <LIS331DLH_ReadAc+0x124>)
8010ca8:    f240 4176   movw    r1, #1142   ; 0x476
8010cac:    f7f4 fb76   bl  800539c <debug_log>
8010cb0:    e78b        b.n 8010bca <LIS331DLH_ReadAc+0x26>
```

Comment: Do you have compiler warnings enabled ? Did you `#include <math.h>` ?

Comment: Note that your code uses imlicitly `double` in values and the function call. Cortex M4F only supports `float` in hardware - but *should* support `double` in software.

Comment: Have you tried `sqrtf(9.7f * 9.7f)` aka the float variant?

Comment: If that is your exact code (please post as well as disassembly) then it is likely the actual square root is done at compile time and the answer is returned and/or whatever you are feeding to print it.  What are you feeding to print it and have you determined if that is also resolved runtime or compile time.  The problem may have (likely has) nothing to do with sqrt() or sqrtf()...

Comment: have you gotten rid of the DEBUG conversion from bits to float yet?  divide the problem in half, keep dividing until you find it.  First division, get rid of the formatted print and examine the raw hex for the values generated by the math.  If it is not the formatted print, then start cutting the math down into individual parts, if you have already done that and it is the sqrt that is the problem, the post just the sqrt example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this all depends on how you are using it.  you need to paste a lot more information/code.  a simple test case, the disassembly of that simple test case, how you are determining the result, etc.

```
#include <math.h>
double fun ( void )
{
    return(sqrt(9.7*9.7));
}
```

as written there is no reason for a math library it is a compile time computation (on the host/development machine).

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   4902        ldr r1, [pc, #8]    ; (c <fun+0xc>)
   2:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <fun+0x8>)
   4:   4770        bx  lr
   6:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   8:   66666666    strbtvs r6, [r6], -r6, ror #12
   c:   40236666    eormi   r6, r3, r6, ror #12
```

building for x86 to show that building for arm does not give a different pre-computed answer.

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 8 <fun+0x8>
   7:   00 
   8:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000000 <.LC0>:
   0:   66                      data16
   1:   66                      data16
   2:   66                      data16
   3:   66                      data16
   4:   66                      data16
   5:   66                      data16
   6:   23                      .byte 0x23
   7:   40                      rex
```

switch to single precision

```
#include <math.h>
float fun ( void )
{
    return(sqrtf(9.7F*9.7F));
}
float fun2 ( void )
{
    return(9.7F);
}
```

and we get the single precision compile time computed answer

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <fun+0x4>)
   2:   4770        bx  lr
   4:   411b3333    tstmi   fp, r3, lsr r3

00000008 <fun2>:
   8:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (c <fun2+0x4>)
   a:   4770        bx  lr
   c:   411b3333    tstmi   fp, r3, lsr r3
```

using clang/llvm instead of gcc:

```
fun:
    ldr.n   r0, .LCPI0_0
    bx  lr
    .align  2
.LCPI0_0:
    .long   1092301619              @ 0x411b3333

fun2:
    ldr.n   r0, .LCPI1_0
    bx  lr
    .align  2
.LCPI1_0:
    .long   1092301619              @ 0x411b3333
```

so you need to repeat that, see if you are calling math functions, if so what are they feeding sqrt, did they actually link in the right stuff, then I would simply print the result in hex.  then debug the other half, is it taking the right 9.7F value and depending on your printing function is it generating the right ascii?

How do I convert (single precision) float to hex you ask?

```
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
   bx lr
```

to verify the compiler is using r0 on the way in and out:

```
unsigned int fun3 ( void )
{
    return(dummy(9.7F));
}

00000010 <fun3>:
  10:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
  12:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (20 <fun3+0x10>)
  14:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <dummy>
  18:   bc08        pop {r3}
  1a:   bc02        pop {r1}
  1c:   4708        bx  r1
  1e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  20:   411b3333    tstmi   fp, r3, lsr r3
```

by simply returning the bits in r0 which come in as float bits dont change, the definition of those bits is a figment of the compiler or programmers imagination anyway, bits are just bits subject to any interpretation.